# Use lapply to plot data in a list and use names of list elements as plot titles

Tags: regex, r, plot

If I have the following list:

```
comp.surv <- list(a = 1:4, b = c(1, 2, 4, 8), c = c(1, 3, 8, 27))
comp.surv
# $a
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# $b
# [1] 1 2 4 8
# 
# $c
# [1]  1  3  8 27
```

I can use `lapply` to plot each list element:

```
lapply(comp.surv, function(x) plot(x))
```

However, I want to include the name of each list element as plot title (`main`). For my example data, the title of each graph would be `a`,`b` and `c` respectively. First thing, is that I have a `gsub` rule that given `comp.surv$a`, I return `a` :

```
gsub(comp.surv\\$([a-z]+), "\\1", deparse(sustitute((comp.surv$a)))
# "a"
```

Which is good. However I cannot embed this result into my `lapply` statement above. Any ideas?

In the mean time I have tried getting round this by creating a function this to include the main parameter:

```
splot <- function(x){
  plot(x, main = gsub(comp.surv\\$([a-z]+), "\\1" deparse(sustitute((x))))
}

lapply(comp.surv, function(x) splot(x))
```

This will plot each sub-variable of comp.surv, but all the titles are blank.

Can anyone recommend if I am going down the right track?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility would be to loop over the `names` of the list:

```
lapply(names(comp.surv), function(x) plot(comp.surv[[x]], main = x))
```

Or slightly more verbose, loop over the list indices:

```
lapply(seq_along(comp.surv), function(x) plot(comp.surv[[x]], main = names(comp.surv)[x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
ns=names(comp.surv)
lapply(ns, function(x) plot(comp.surv[[x]], main=x,ylab="y"))
```

Comment: A similar answer is already posted.